# jquery complex animation bugs up

Tags: jquery, image, animation, settimeout

im trying to create something in jquery but it just keeps bugging up.

here is the sample:

http://www.migo.no/testing.php

as you can see the frame is supposed to be enlarged when u hover above it for more than 400 ms. it seems to work but when i hover both images very fast back and forward, the whole thing just bugges up. I dont really know how to solve this.

the code can be edited here:
http://jsfiddle.net/robertpitt/8u24b/

js:

http://www.migo.no/js/testing.js

css:

http://www.migo.no/css/testing.css

i hope i can get some advice on how to prevent this from totally bugging up.

Regards,
Alexander

Comment: @Alexander The sample redirects to google?

Comment: yup , same here.it redirects to http://www.google.no/

Comment: sorry, i forgot to remove it. its back on

Comment: For users wanting to do some live testing: http://jsfiddle.net/robertpitt/8u24b/

Comment: meo , adding a semicolon is also meaningless in javascript, it still doesnt make me comment everyone that does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just learned about clearTimeout();

Problem solved